# Disabling Click Delay, Dell XPS13 Windows 10 Home Edition, Microsoft Touchpad

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse, touchpad, dell-xps

**tl;dr - How do I disable click delay on a Windows 10 Dell xps13 9360 laptop?**

This quarantine has got me trying to play video games again. I loaded up CSGO for the first time on this machine and discovered that I couldn't shoot (mouseclick 1 (left-click)) while I moved (holding down any keyboard key). Outside of CSGO, I tested in a Notepad file, holding down the 'W' key and trying to click off the Notepad window, this also did not work. Notepad remained the window in focus, and the Ws continued to roll in.

The main solutions I've seen online that work for some people but did not work for me are:

1. Setting touchpad sensitivity to "Most sensitive"
2. Uninstalling the touchpad driver and restarting my laptop
3. Turning the touchpad off

It's obvious to me that this is a feature, not a bug. It makes sense that as you were typing on a laptop you wouldn't want the touchpad tap to click feature to work when your palms hit the touchpad.

Some solutions online that seemed to work for some users include disabling click delay and palm sensitivity on the touchpad settings. I have searched *everywhere* I could, and these settings *do not* exist, or are completely buried/hidden on the machine that I have.

If there is any more information I can provide, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my machine was auto-loading on startup an application called TouchFreeze.exe. Guess what the sole purpose of this executable is?

Mystery solved.